# UIActivityViewController not showing PDF option

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I know there are many posts on this type of thing.  And I believe I have tried all of the suggestions.  I have a very simple problem.  I have a url to a PDF and I want to be able to "share" this to the adobe pdf reader app.  To remove one of the possible issues I took the PDF I was downloading and put it into my bundle so it was local.  I am on iOS 8.4.  Here is the code I tried:

```
NSURL * url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @ "data" ofType: @ "pdf"]];

//Tried with the data in the file
NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
UIActivityViewController *act=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[data2] applicationActivities:nil];

//Tried with just the URL
UIActivityViewController *act=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[url2] applicationActivities:nil];

act.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = button;
act.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
[self presentViewController:act animated:YES completion:nil];
return;
```

Neither of these show the PDF option. I of course have it installed and have run it once to make sure its registered properly.  Both of these I can share to Mail and the actual file is sent fine but the only share options I get are Mail, Copy and Print.  I would like to see the other options like Open in iBooks and Open in Adobe Acrobat like I get from safari.

Ideas?

Comment: If you want to share a file with other apps, use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, not `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: BTW - on a real device, you can not download a file to the app bundle. It is read-only. Save the file in the Documents folder or the Caches folder if it is a temporary file. One of the many reason to test on real devices.